# Changing color on all svg

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, random

i'm trying to use an effect i found on Codepen, changing colours on SVG.
There's an issue on the script that makes the effect affect only the first SVG and not the others on the page as i would like.

Any help? thanks

```js
var select = function(s) {
    return document.querySelector(s);
};
var svgItem = select('svg');
var chars = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');

var randomColor = function () {
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    color += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  return color;
};

setInterval(function () {
  svgItem.style.fill = randomColor();
}, 1500);
```

```css
svg {
   fill: #000000;   
   transition: fill 1.5s ease;
   -webkit-transition: fill 1.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg height="100" width="100">
<circle cx="40" cy="40" r="40"></circle>
</svg>


<svg height="100" width="100">
<circle cx="40" cy="40" r="40"></circle>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `querySelectorAll` instead of `querySelector` to get all svg elements.`querySelectorAll` will give array then you can use index to access each `svg`:

```js
var select = function(s) {
    return document.querySelectorAll(s);
};
var svgItem = select('svg');
var chars = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');

var randomColor = function () {
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    color += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  return color;
};

setInterval(function () {
   svgItem.forEach(function(svg) {
svg.style.fill = randomColor();});   
}, 1500);
```

```css
svg {
   fill: #000000;   
   transition: fill 1.5s ease;
   -webkit-transition: fill 1.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg height="100" width="100">
<circle cx="40" cy="40" r="40"></circle>
</svg>


<svg height="100" width="100">
<circle cx="40" cy="40" r="40"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Great!!! Adding selectorAll and "svgItem[X].style.fill = randomColor()" for each SVG as you explained. Thanks

Comment: @Danielillo you can accept either of the answers.use index only if there are 2 or 3 svgs and they are fixed, for dynamic number of svg use updated code.

Answer (score 2):

`document.querySelector()` returns only the first element found.

Try `document.querySelectorAll()` and iterate over the received list.

```
var select = function(s) {
  return document.querySelectorAll(s);
};
var svgItems = select('svg');
var chars = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');

var randomColor = function () {
var color = '#';
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
  color += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  return color;
};

setInterval(function () {
  svgItems.forEach(item => {item.style.fill = randomColor();});
}, 1500);
```